# android- playing a video from sd card

Tags: android, media-player, android-video-player

I want to create a simple video player using mediaPlayer.. So I did the code which I have given below. But I'm having a problem here because the video is not visible, but the audio is playing. 
In my XML file I used a simple VideoView.

```
    package com.Android.Simple;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.widget.VideoView;

    public class SimpleVideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

        private VideoView _UIVideo;
        SurfaceHolder _videoHolder;

        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_video_view);

            _UIVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
            MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
            String _path = "/sdcard/abc.3gp";
            _videoHolder = _UIVideo.getHolder();

             try {
                _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(_path);
                _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_videoHolder);
                _mediaPlayer.prepare();
                _mediaPlayer.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
             }
    }
```

and the manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Android.Simple"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".SimpleVideoPlayerActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>





    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/VVSimpleVideo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this Code

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        videoView.setVideoPath(path);


        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

Comment: Sam, this is using VideoView... I wanna use MediaPlayer

Answer (score 2):

can u show your manifest file ?add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 2):

On android developer site you have very simple demo:

[Media Player](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html)

change your layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </SurfaceView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and start activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerDemo_Video.class);
i.putExtra("path", path);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I dont know why, for some reason even this example doesn display the video... it only plays the audio